# Where are TIGER's "Consolidated Cities"?

Tags: tiger

The TIGER reference docs make numerous references to Consolidated Cities. It's also one of the checkboxes on TIGERWeb.

But there are only 5 files in the Consolidate cities directory and available for download (http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2011/CONCITY/). And I can't find any in the Places file (i.e. no lines have MTFCC='G4120').

So can someone please explain how to find which "Consolidated City" (if any) any given (lat,long) belongs too in the US ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

*"A Consolidated City is a unit of local government for which the functions of an incorporated place and its county or minor civil division (MCD) have merged. This action results in both the primary incorporated place and the county or MCD continuing to exist as legal entities, even though the county or MCD performs few or no governmental functions and has few or no elected officials. Where this occurs, and where one or more other incorporated places in the county or MCD continue to function as separate governments, even though they have been included in the consolidated government, the primary incorporated place is referred to as a consolidated city. The Census Bureau classifies the separately incorporated places within the consolidated city as place entities and creates a separate place (balance) record for the portion of the consolidated city not within any other place."*

http://tigerweb.geo.census.gov/tigerwebmain/TIGERweb_geography_details.html

**"Note that the TIGER/Line Shapefiles do not include empty shapefiles. For example, if a state does not contain any consolidated cities, then no consolidated city shapefile is created for that state. "**

http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/faq.html

So only 5 States have them.

Comment: Yes I read the definition over and over and I see there are only 5 files. But I also see a couple "balance" places in the places file so why are there consolidated cities if they are broken down into separate Places...